# pyspark sql select from other table when is null with condition

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to build a select query to fill nulls in a dataframe with the content of other dataframe
df1.
If in `df1` is null, it needs to check in `df2` the value with `df2.date = df1.prev_date`

My code now is

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")
q="select NVL(b.value, select a.value from table2 a where a.date=b.prev_date_def) as value from table1 b"
df_out = spark.sql(q)
```

But this code is failing because needs an aggregated function.
Error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Correlated scalar subqueries must
> be aggregated: Filter (cast(date#269 as date) =
> outer(prev_date#1500))...

df1

```
   +------------+-------+------------+
   |    date    |  value|  prev_date |
   +------------+-------+------------+
 1 | 23/11/2021 |  0.141| 24/11/2021 |
 2 | 24/11/2021 |   0.17| 23/11/2021 |
 3 | 25/11/2021 |   null| 24/11/2021 |
 4 | 26/11/2021 |  0.135| 25/11/2021 |
```

df2

```
   +------------+-------+
   |    date    |  value|
   +------------+-------+
 1 | 23/11/2021 |   1.00|
 2 | 24/11/2021 |   2.00|
 3 | 25/11/2021 |   3.00|
 4 | 26/11/2021 |   4.00|
```

expected df_out

```
    +------------+-------+------------+
    |    date    |  value|  prev_date |
    +------------+-------+------------+
  1 | 23/11/2021 |  0.141| 24/11/2021 |
  2 | 24/11/2021 |   0.17| 23/11/2021 |
  3 | 25/11/2021 |   2.00| 24/11/2021 |
  4 | 26/11/2021 |  0.135| 25/11/2021 |
```

Comment: Is it ok that the first row of df1 is 24/11/2021, or should it be 22/11/2021 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join + `coalesce` should do the job:

```py
result = df1.join(df2, df1["prev_date"] == df2["date"], "left").select(
    df1["date"],
    F.coalesce(df1["value"], df2["value"]).alias("value"),
    df1["prev_date"]
)

result.show()

#+----------+-----+----------+
#|      date|value| prev_date|
#+----------+-----+----------+
#|24/11/2021| 0.17|23/11/2021|
#|23/11/2021|0.141|24/11/2021|
#|25/11/2021|  2.0|24/11/2021|
#|26/11/2021|0.135|25/11/2021|
#+----------+-----+----------+
```

Equivalent SparkSQL query:

```py
result = spark.sql("""
SELECT t1.date,
       coalesce(t1.value, t2.value) as value,
       t1.prev_date
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON    t1.prev_date = t2.date
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col("date"))
new=(df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed('value','value_2'), on=['date'], how='left')#Join the two df's renaming values in df2
        .withColumn("value", coalesce(col('value'),lag("value_2").over(w))).drop('value_2')#Fill the col value with a shifted value of value_2
    )

+-----------+-----+----------+
|       date|value| prev_date|
+-----------+-----+----------+
|223/11/2021|0.141|24/11/2021|
| 24/11/2021| 0.17|23/11/2021|
| 25/11/2021|  2.0|24/11/2021|
| 26/11/2021|0.135|25/11/2021|
+-----------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: This should be a solution only if `df1` doesn't have column `prev_date` otherwise it's just complicating things.

Comment: @blackbishop, an alternative approach :-)